# Blender crashing on start

Tags: windows

I started blender up today and it crashes on launch. I uninstalled, and re-installed to no avail. I tried debugging and the following information is available:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBC58BC2A0 (Wacom_Tablet.dll) in blender.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

As the error refers to a "Wacom_tablet.dll", I have been using the tablet with blender with no issue until today.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had problems running Blender 2.79 with Windows 10 and apparently you need to install all windows updates to be able to use it properly. I decided to install Blender manually instead of using the auto-install feature and had no problems. You may want to try that first. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I eventually resolved this by uninstalling anything wacom related, and blender related and then re-installing the respective software and drivers.

I am running windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 has been creating way too many problems for me, next I'm switching to Linux and Wacom told me that their new devices are Linux compatible!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by uninstalling all blender software, and all wacom drivers and software. Thereafter I re-installed the respective drivers and software.

Note: This issue seems to have arose at random as I have been using the wacom tablet with that specific driver version for a number of weeks. It should be noted that this error was presented itself in blender vers. 2.77 and 2.79.